# Question regarding isomorphism of locally-free sheaves under an etale pushforward

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be an etale morphism of smooth varieties over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.
Suppose there are two locally free sheaves $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$ such that $f_*\mathcal{E}\simeq f_*\mathcal{F}$ .

**Question:** Is there any result that might help us to conclude that $\mathcal{E}\simeq\mathcal{F}$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. For instance, assume $f$ has degree $2$, and $\tau \colon X \to X$ is the covering involution. Then
$$
f_*\mathcal{E} \cong f_*(\tau_*\mathcal{E}), 
$$
but $\tau_*\mathcal{E} \not \cong \mathcal{E}$ in general.

For an explicit example, take
$$
X = (\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1) \setminus \Delta,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal, let $\tau$ be the permutation of factors (hence $Y$ is the complement of a smooth conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$), and define $\mathcal{E}$ as the restriction of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1,0)$.